# How do I solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{jk}} { \sum_j w_{jk} . o_j }$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, neural-networks

Please I want to know why $\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}} { \sum_j W_{jk} . o_j }$ =  $o_j$

I know $\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}} {  W_{jk} . o_j }$ =  $o_j$ but I got confused by the summation symbol.

I was reading it from "MAKE YOUR OWN NEURAL NETWORK" book (page 96) by TARIQ RASHIQ. $W_{jk}$ represent the weight connecting node j to node k. And $o_j$ represent the output of node j

But then what I was thinking was:
if the partial differentiation of $W_{jk}$ with respect to $W_{jk}$ is one , then it means we are getting $\sum1 . oj$ and $\sum1$ is 1. So finally we will get $o_j$

Comment: The derivative is a linear operator, so the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives. So that should give you $\sum o_j$. How that is equal to $o_j$ beats me. It would help if you properly define the W and o functions

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo That is what I also don't understand.  $o_j$ = $sigmoid(\sum_iW_{ik} . o_i)$ where $i$ is the node in the previous layer connecting to it

Comment: What is "sigmoid"? Nonetheless, $o_j$ seems to be a function of $W_{ik} $, so is your partial derivative of W times o really correct?

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo maybe this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Comment: Something about the expression is wrong.  The $j$ in the summation is a dummy variable, and despite using the same letter, has no actual connection to the weight the derivative is being taken with respect to.

Comment: So that may be it.  The summation is an expression that depends only on $k$.  Break it out, and you have $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{jk}} \left(w_{1k} o_1 + w_{2k}o_2 + \cdots + w_{jk}o_j + \cdots + w_{nk} o_n\right) = o_j$.  That could be what they have in mind, though I'd say the presentation could be a bit confusing, if so.

Comment: @BrianTung what you are saying makes sense to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please I want to know why $\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{jk}} { \sum_j W_{jk} . o_j } =  o_j$
>
> ...but I got confused by the summation symbol.

That is not unusual.   You have overloaded the $j$ token; one use is as a free token, and the other is bound to the summation.   Although this is legal, it is often a source of confusion.   For clarity you should use a fresh token in the series.   Recall that $\sum_j a_j=\sum_i a_i$ .

Then we may partition the series, extracting the one term where the series index equals the free token from all the others, where they do not match.

$$\dfrac{\partial\quad}{\partial W_{jk}} { \sum_i W_{ik} \cdot o_i } ~=~  \dfrac{\partial\quad}{\partial W_{jk}} ( W_{jk} \cdot o_j )+\sum_{i~:~i\neq j}\dfrac{\partial\quad}{\partial W_{jk}}(W_{ik}\cdot o_i)$$

You can handle the first term, while the remainder vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rewrite the term
you want to differentiate as
$$
\phi
= 
\sum_l W_{lk}o_l
= 
\left(
W_{jk}o_j
+
C
\right)
$$
where
$C$ is a term that DOES not depend on
$W_{jk}$.

Now the result is clear that
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial W_{jk}} 
= o_j
$$